# How to update an array property of a component from an action?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write an `Ember.Component` containing two paragraphs in an array, a textarea and actions to load the paragraphs into the textarea for editing, then save the changes.  (At the moment, `ESC` press saves changes, ideally it would be "live" -- a change I'll work out later.)

I've prepared a [JSbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gusemeciqevo/1/edit?html,js,output), the rest of this is explanation and pseudo-code.

The component template:

```
  {{#each p in paragraphs}}
    <p {{action 'selectParagraph' p}}>{{p}}</p>
  {{/each}}

  {{textarea value=selectedParagraph escape-press='updateParagraph'}}
```

The component's pseudo-code:

```
  paragraphs: ['one', 'two'],

  selectParagraph: f(p) { this.set('selectedIndex', paragraphs.indexOf(p)); },

  selectedParagraph: f() { this.get('paragraphs')[this.get('selectedIndex')] ; },

  updateParagraph: f(data) {
      var p = this.get('paragraphs');
      p[this.get('selectedIndex')] = data;
  }
```

However, the original paragraph is not updated after the `updateParagraph()` call.  In the generated page source, there are metamorph script tags around the paragraphs rendered by the `#each` loop, so I believe Ember knows the `<p>` content is dynamic.

I suspect I'm missing something obvious, this seems like a fairly straight-forward task.
I've presumably failed to set up something such that the `paragraph` array changes cause a re-render; or am not changing the array element (string) itself in the "Ember-way".

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_replace

```
var p = this.get('paragraphs'),
    idx = this.get('selectedIndex');
p.replace(idx, 1, [data]);
```

You can just wrap your array with Ember.A([]) to get the replace functionality.

```
Em.A([ 'First component embedded paragraph.', 'Second component embedded paragraph.' ])
```

Additionally you'll run into issues when you assign to a computed property, so it's usually better to avoid that pattern.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuyit/1/edit

Or you can `removeAt` and `insertAt`

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I'll read the MutableArray documentation too.

Comment: I am somewhat confused now. I did look at Ember.A before posting, but docs indicate prototypes are extended by default, so I didn't think I needed to use it. If they are extended, what is Ember.A([]) doing that [] isn't? (I can research that.) "..avoid that pattern.." -- what do you mean by "that pattern"? -- avoid use of replace/removeAt/insertAt, and prefer an observer (as in your JSbin)?  Thanks again, I appreciate this; I'm now unstuck.

Comment: Or, perhaps you meant use `Ember.A()` explicitly in a component, because it will improve component re-use?  For example, where `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` might be false.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I always assume they are off because one of our projects has them off.  I'm saying avoid the pattern setting a computed property.  When you bind an input to a computed property you are not only getting from the computed property, but also setting the computed property.  Try your code with the computed property, the input box will stop working the first time you change it.

Comment: Ah; I did notice it stopped working, but only tried for a few seconds before leaving the keyboard. I had a guess at the problem but was going to debug later -- I didn't realize it was a computed property related though, so you've saved me time again.  Also, I had wondered about using an observer, so thanks for that example in particular.  Cheers the for extra discussion in comments.